# How do i convert grease pencil objects back into mesh?

Tags: grease-pencil

I converted a mesh into Gpencil. Then messed around until I didn't have any undos left. Now I can't get my mesh back. Can someone help me recover my mesh? Obviously I should have saved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three “time portals” you can try:

1. The blend1 file saved before each Blender session begins. Will take you back one blender session.
2. File -> Recover -> Last Session. Will open Blender to whatever was in it when you last quit normally, even if you did not save.
3. File -> Recover -> Auto save. Opens a file dialogue to a folder containing various “points in time” over the history of your blender usage. Use the sort system to put newer files first and avoid confusion.

If this doesn’t work, check your local general store for plutonium.

Comment: Thanks that's the first place I went. Unfortunately it saved right after I switched lol. freaking annoying. I really got to get better at my saving. I've been messing around with the python API but GPencil changes the mesh data some how. I can't even find where it's data is hiding.

Comment: @GrahamThomas Try creating a new default cube, and switching the mesh data block to something else. If there’s nothing there, then I think you’ll have to start over.